# insertAdjacentHTML not inserting passed string correctly

Tags: javascript

I want to insert html after a particular element but insertAdjacentHTML wont let me add a closing tag first.

If I do

```
elm.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '</div><section class="block">');
```

the expected result is

```
 <element></element></div><section class="block">
```

the result it's returning

```
 <element></element><section class="block"></div>
```

Is there a way around this?

**Edit:**

Basically what i'm trying to do is loop through each element and split them into two divs

```
 <div class="column">
     <div class="block">block 1</div>
     <div class="block">block 2</div>
     <div class="block">block 3</div>
     <div class="block">block 4</div>
     <div class="block">block 5</div>
     <div class="block">block 6</div>
     <div class="block">block 7</div>
     <div class="block">block 8</div>
 </div>
```

Expected result

```
 <div class="column">
     <div class="block">block 1</div>
     <div class="block">block 2</div>
     <div class="block">block 3</div>
     <div class="block">block 4</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
     <div class="block">block 5</div>
     <div class="block">block 6</div>
     <div class="block">block 7</div>
     <div class="block">block 8</div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
    let half = Math.ceil(blocks.length / 2 - 1);
    blocks[half].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '</div><div class="column">');
```

Comment: Using the DOM API you can **never** add/create/insert invalid HTML. `</div>` or any other closing tag without its opening tag, is invalid HTML.

Comment: Is there another way to do this?

Comment: So you want to insert `<section class="block">` after the `div` that surrounds `element`?

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: You cannot split a div using text manipulation. You will have to resort to JS, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your requirement right, this is what you want to do:

```
elm.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<section class="block"></section>');
```

If the `div` is not the direct parent element, you might want to use `Element.closest(selector)` instead:

```
elm.closest('div.myDiv').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<section class="block"></section>');
```

## update

You have elaborated on your requirements further, this is how to do it in Javascript:

```js
const blocks = [...document.querySelectorAll('.block')];

const middle = Math.ceil(blocks.length / 2 - 1);

const column = document.querySelector('.column');

const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

const col1 = document.createElement('div');
col1.className = 'column';
const col2 = document.createElement('div');
col2.className = 'column';

blocks.forEach((block, index) => {
  if (index <= middle) {
    col1.appendChild(block)
  } else {
    col2.appendChild(block)
  }
})

parent.removeChild(column)
parent.appendChild(col1);
parent.appendChild(col2);
```

```css
.column+.column {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">block 1</div>
    <div class="block">block 2</div>
    <div class="block">block 3</div>
    <div class="block">block 4</div>
    <div class="block">block 5</div>
    <div class="block">block 6</div>
    <div class="block">block 7</div>
    <div class="block">block 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Resulting DOM:

[image: Resulting DOM]

Comment: Use the DOM inspector and you'll see the DOM is exactly what you are looking for.